# Only Show a Watermark When Document is Printed

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010, macros, watermark

I have a series of ISO controlled documents that need to have a watermark appear **only** when printed that says something like "UNCONTROLLED WHEN PRINTED". This watermark would appear in the footer of the printed document. I do not want this watermark to appear when the document is read electronically.

Looked around online and couldn't find a solution that works the way I want it to. I can setup a watermark in the print driver settings but that isn't the solution I need. It looks like I will have to use VBA to accomplish this as this isn't a feature in Microsoft Word 2010.

Comment: You are correct.  You need to use VBA to acomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this text hidden. Then set in print profile to print hidden text. Check [this](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/word-hidden-text/) page for detailed instructions

Comment: Yes, but if you have to be careful if you have any other hidden text that you don't want printed.